# c# winform Resizing button on different form

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I want to resize my button on `form2` using the button on `form1`.

This is my code and it gives me error:

```
public void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text);
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text);
    f2.button8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(x, y);
}
```

It has an error at `Form2.button8.Size` .. I made my `button8` Public so it can be accessed..
but still it gives me error *"Form2.button8 is inaccessible because of its protection level"*..

this is my button8 at form2

public void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
}

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: try `Form2 f2=new Form2(); f2.button8.....`

Comment: that one solve the second error .. but still unaccessible because of its protection lvl ..

Comment: what protection level has your Form2 class? Are namespaces defined correctly?

Comment: When your calling the Form2 with object that time you change the size of button int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text); int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text); Form2 frm = new Form2(); frm.button8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(x, y);

Comment: this is my button8 at form2 .. 

public void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: public void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

your answer solved the second error but not the first ..

Comment: wouldn't it make sense to name frm `frm2` LOL

Comment: `Jurel` go to `Form2 then look for the Button, Single Click on it and set the `Modifier` from `Private` to `Public`

Answer (score 4):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2.button1.Size = new Size(int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text));
    }
}
}
```

I made button1 on the form2.designer.cs internal.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    partial class Form2
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(95, 89);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "buttonForm2";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form2";
            this.Text = "Form2";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

    //This is where you change from private to internal
        internal System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
```

Comment: go into the form2.designer.cs and change the button from private to internal or public. the handler can remain private and should.

Comment: i just did it and it worked. can provide full example if needed